# Sum AWK with if

Tags: awk

I have this File.

```
House.csv
M2018&03,HOUSE,BOX_X,16
M2018&03,HOUSE,FENCE_A,2
M2018&03,HOUSE,IRON_V + WINDOWS,1
M2018&03,HOUSE,DOOR + ROOF,7
M2018&03,HOUSE,TABLE + TV + LAPTOP,1
M2018&03,HOUSE,RADIO_A + RADIO_B + RADIO_C,3
M2018&03,HOUSE,CHAIR_A + CHAIR_B,2
```

I am using AWK change the file and to add the number of the line in itself.

```
awk -F"," '{ gsub(/\_/,"\&",$1); if(NR < 10){print $1","$2",0"NR","$3","$4}else{print $1","$2","NR","$3","$4}}' House.csv > House2.csv

House2.csv
M2018_03,HOUSE,01,BOX_X,16
M2018_03,HOUSE,02,FENCE_A,2
M2018_03,HOUSE,03,IRON_V + WINDOWS,1
M2018_03,HOUSE,04,DOOR + ROOF,7
M2018_03,HOUSE,05,TABLE + TV + LAPTOP,1
M2018_03,HOUSE,06,RADIO_A + RADIO_B + RADIO_C,3
M2018_03,HOUSE,07,CHAIR_A + CHAIR_B,2
```

Now I want a to put this awk into previous awk together.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{a[$1","$2]+=$5}END{ for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' House2.csv
```

Notice that I want the sum of all values from the 5th column.
    M2018_03,HOUSE,32

To become a file like this.

```
M2018_03,HOUSE,01,BOX_X,16,32
M2018_03,HOUSE,02,FENCE_A,2,32
M2018_03,HOUSE,03,IRON_V + WINDOWS,1,32
M2018_03,HOUSE,04,DOOR + ROOF,7,32
M2018_03,HOUSE,05,TABLE + TV + LAPTOP,1,32
M2018_03,HOUSE,06,RADIO_A + RADIO_B + RADIO_C,3,32
M2018_03,HOUSE,07,CHAIR_A + CHAIR_B,2,32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution which will save OP from using multiple `awk`s.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{sum[$1]+=$NF;next} {val=$1;sub("&","_",val);$3=sprintf("%02d",FNR) OFS $3;print $0,sum[$1]}' OFS=, house.csv  house.csv
```

---

Following may help you on same.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{sum[$1]+=$NF;next} {print $0,sum[$1]}' OFS=, house.csv  house.csv
```

Explanation: Adding explanation of above code too now.

```
awk -F, '                    ##Making field separator as comma here.
FNR==NR{                     ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first time house.csv will be read.
   sum[$1]+=$NF;             ##Creating an array named sum whose index is first field and value is last field and adding its value to same index items.
   next}                     ##next will skip all further statements now.
{                            ##This block will be executed when 2nd time house.csv is getting executed.
   print $0,sum[$1]          ##Printing current line along with array sum value whose index is current line first field.
}
' OFS=, house.csv  house.csv ##Setting OFS as comma and mentioning Input_file 2 times here.
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude.
I put your code in my first awk and it's worked.

    awk -F"," 'FNR==NR{sum[$5]+=$NF;next} { gsub(/\_/,"\&",$1); if(NR < 10){print $1","$2",0"NR","$3","$4","sum[$5]}else{print $1","$2","NR","$3","$4","sum[$5]}}' house.csv house.csv

Comment: @ebk, glad that it worked for you, cheers happy learning keep sharing and keep posting enjoy :)

Comment: With your help, I have skipped 3 or 4 steps.

Comment: @ebk, please check my EDIT solution now, if you use that you need not to use 2 `awk`s using pipe, let me know on same then.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call awk multiple times:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR == FNR {sum[$1,$2] += $NF; next} 
    {
        $NF = $NF OFS sum[$1,$2]
        gsub(/&/, "_", $1)
        $2 = $2 OFS sprintf("%02d", FNR)
        print
    }
' House.csv House.csv
```

Loop over the file twice: first to calculate the sum, the second time to apply all the modifications to the line.

Outputs

```
M2018_03,HOUSE,01,BOX_X,16,32
etc
```

Comment: Yes but that's where the question seems to be heading.